# Protractor - Sometimes test cases that including windows handling are failed on "no such window"

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

Since I've integrated my scripts to Jenkins,

sometimes part of my test cases are including `switchTo().window(handles[0])` are failed.

I've tried to add more **wait** or **sleep** before and after the actions but it doesn't make my test cases stable.

**Error:**

> [31mFatal error: 11:03:56.527 WARN - Exception thrown
>       org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window

**Test case for example:**

```
it('Settings - Redirect to links - FAQ', function() {
      element.all(by.css("a.faq-link")).first();
       browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/a'))), 30000);
       browser.driver.sleep(1000);
       element(by.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/a')).click();

       var mainWindow;
            browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(
                function(handles) {
                    mainWindow = handles[0]; //at this point there should be only 1 window
                }
            );

      browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {    
         handles.forEach(function(handle) {
           if (handle !== mainWindow) {
              browser.driver.switchTo().window(handle);
              browser.driver.sleep(3000);
              expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("some url address");
            }
        });
     });
    });

    it(Settings - Staff', function() {
       element.all(by.css('[ng-click="start_create()"]')).first();
       browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
         browser.driver.close();
         browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
         browser.driver.sleep(3000);
      });
      //-=- switch to iFrame handler -=-
      browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
      browser.driver.switchTo().frame("timegate_iframe");
       element(by.css("a.staff.section-item")).click();
       browser.driver.sleep(1000);
       browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('[ng-click="start_create()"]'))), 30000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for any change in open windows number. Only then try to send commands to your current window.

Here's a tiny function that catch any change in windows number and return True/False accordingly:

```
def wait_for_diff_in_windows_number(self, timer=10, currentWindows=1):
    startTime = time.time()
    openWindows = len(self.driver.window_handles)
    while (time.time() - startTime) < timer :
        openWindows = len(self.driver.window_handles)
        if openWindows != currentWindows :
            return True
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    return False
```

Comment: Can you please explain me in JS? I don't understand the syntax of this.. thanks

Comment: See my answer below. It's a lame translation (I'm not a JS expert), but it has the same logic

Answer (score 0):

```
function wait_for_diff_in_windows_number(obj, timer, currentWindows) {
  timer = timer || 10;
  currentWindows = currentWindows || 1;
  var startTime = new Date();
  var openWindows = obj.driver.window_handles.length;
  while((new Date() - startTime) < timer) {
    openWindows = openWindows;
    if(openWindows !== currentWindows) {
      return true;
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {

      }, 1)
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```